# Ionic2 Push notification with background processing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-pushplugin, ionic.io

I am using ionic.io to send push to my app. I have following body

```
{"tokens":["DeviceToken"],
"profile":"Profile",
"notification":{ "payload": {
      "type": "loadCategories"
    },
    "ios": {
      "content_available": 1
    },
    "android": {
      "content_available": "1"
    }}}
```

Type script code.

```
var push = Push.init({
                android: {
                    senderID: "ID"
                },
                ios: {
                    alert: "true",
                    badge: true,
                    sound: 'false'
                },
                windows: {}
            });
            if((<any>push).error) {
                console.log((<any>push).error);
                return;                
            };            
        push.on('registration', (data)=>{
            console.log(data.registrationId);
            this.pushToken = data.registrationId;
            this.updateToken();

        });
        push.on("notification", (data)=>{
            console.log(data);            
            // if(data.additionalData.payload && data.additionalData.payload.type == 'categoryEvent') {
            //     console.log("at date")
            // }
        });     
        push.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);            
        });
```

Idea is that I need to send push to user and load data from the server. But problem is that if app is in background then notification event is not fired. It works only if app is active. But as soon as i understand from documentation it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Known issue that has been addressed with setting `content_available = 1`. See https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/93 for more.

Comment: I will try it soon, because problem is that i am using ionic.io to push data

Comment: It helps, after i moved to firebase i can send right payload :)